# How to click on Systemtray program through AutoITx in java?

Tags: autoit

How to click on Systemtray program through AutoITx in java?

I know there are many library files available like "GuiToolBar.au3" which we need to include in AutoIt program, but we cannot import it in Java, so we cannot use method available in  in java while using AutoItX and Jacob library.

Comment: Is it an item that's always visible in the system tray, or could it be in the extra items window thing (or expanded list on vista and before)? This should be possible with the standard AutoIt functions.

Comment: Thanks for reply. It is an item that is always visible in the Systemtray. There is no any standard autoit function available for it. It is only possible using GuiToolBar.au3, but how to use that library in java through AutoItx jar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved this using below code:

public static void Func_LaunchSystrayProgram() throws IOException

{

```
    try {
        AutoItX objX = new AutoItX();
        int indexinSystray = 3;
        boolean resultflag = false;
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        boolean isfocus = objX.controlFocus(
                "[CLASS:Shell_TrayWnd]", "User Promoted Notification Area",
                "[CLASS:ToolbarWindow32]");
        objX.sleep(2000);

        System.out.println("isfocus:" + isfocus);
        if (isfocus == true) {

            for (int count = 0; count < indexinSystray; count++) {
                boolean clcik = objX.controlSend(
                        "[CLASS:Shell_TrayWnd]", "",
                        "[CLASS:ToolbarWindow32; ID:1504]", "{RIGHT}",
                        false);
                // objX.send("{RIGHT}");
                objX.sleep(1000);
            }
            objX.sleep(1000);


            objX.controlSend("[CLASS:Shell_TrayWnd]",
                    "", "[CLASS:ToolbarWindow32; ID:1504]", "{ENTER}",
                    false);

            String activeWintitle = objX
                    .winGetTitle("[ACTIVE]");

            System.out.println("activeWintitle: " + activeWintitle);
            if ("ProgramTitle".equalsIgnoreCase(activeWintitle)) {
                System.out.println("Title Match");
                resultflag = true;

            } else {
                System.out.println("Title Not Matched");
                resultflag = false;
            }

        } else {
            resultflag = false;
        }

        if (resultflag == true) {
            Update_Report("executed");
        } else {
            Update_Report("failed");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        Update_Report("failed", e);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's just a left click then `ControlCommand` with `SendCommandId` normally works, and would allow you to do it in native AutoIt.

Alternatively, you will have to import the winapi function directly. Most links seem to point to [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna) for that. If you are not sure about what functions to use, then look at the source code for `GUIToolbar.au3`, and usually it can be figured out from that.